EM waves and electron waves
If electrons are also waves then how can they produce EM waves when they "jiggle" due to temperature rise

electrons are not waves. The more precise description could be "a quantum particle", which is an object that does not behave neither as a (classical) particle or wave

In quantum field theory all electrons and positrons are quanta of one field (which can “wave”) and all photons are quanta of another field (the EM one, which can also “wave”). These two fields interact with each other everywhere in spacetime. Every fundamental particle is a quantum of some fundamental field, so wave–particle duality applies to all quanta.

These explain some things about particles vs waves - How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon? and Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?
